# SQL - Return rows where date is given date or date plus dynamic days

Tags: sql

Ok the title isn't a great help I'm sorry but this is what I'm trying to do.

I have an Events table with an EventDateFrom date field and a NumberOfDays int field.

The user selects a date and I need to return the rows where the event was going on on that date.

So say there's an event with the EventDateFrom of November 16th 2011 and the NumberOfDays was 4 (i.e. the event went on for 4 days) and the user selectts the date November 17th 2011 it SHOULD return this event.

This is what i was trying:

```
SELECT Path FROM Events WHERE
(
EventDateFrom >= '2011/11/17 00:00:00' --the date selected by the user
)
and
(
Events.EventDateFrom <= DATEADD(D,NumberOfDays,EventDateFrom)
)
```

But it just returns everything on or after the 17th

I do sort of understand why its returning everything after the date, but what I don't understand is how I should be doing this, all I know is the way I'm doing it is wrong

Thank you so much for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
SELECT Path FROM Events WHERE
'2011/11/17 00:00:00' BETWEEN EventDateFrom AND DATEADD(D,NumberOfDays,EventDateFrom)
```

EDIT - as per comments:

```
SELECT 
Path, 
eventdatefrom, 
NumberOfDays 
FROM Events 
WHERE '2011/11/17 00:00:00' BETWEEN 
      EventDateFrom AND 
      (select case when NumberOfDays = 0 then DATEADD(D,NumberOfDays,EventDateFrom) else DATEADD(D,NumberOfDays-1,EventDateFrom) end)
```

Comment: I'd think that 4 days are the 16, 17, 18 and 19 of November. This will include the 20th.

Comment: My final solution was based on Yahia's suggestion, i just had to make an amendment to subtract 1 from the number of days and also handle when the number of days was zero (i didnt even realise there were events where it was 0 so my apologies for not mentioning this)  SELECT Path, eventdatefrom, NumberOfDays FROM Events WHERE
'2011/11/17 00:00:00' BETWEEN EventDateFrom AND  
(select case
when NumberOfDays = 0
then DATEADD(D,NumberOfDays,EventDateFrom) 
else DATEADD(D,NumberOfDays-1,EventDateFrom)
end)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need:

```
SELECT Path FROM Events 
WHERE
    EventDateFrom >= '2011-11-17'    --- the date selected by the user
  AND 
    '2011-11-17' < DATEADD(D, NumberOfDays, EventDateFrom)

             --- ^ --- notice the "<", not "<=" here, so you have only dates 
                   --- from '2011-11-16 00:00:00' up to '2011-11-19 23:59:59'
```

Answer (score 0):

So close already - try:

```
SELECT Path FROM Events WHERE
(
EventDateFrom <= '2011/11/17 00:00:00' --the date selected by the user
)
and
(
'2011/11/17 00:00:00' <= DATEADD(D,NumberOfDays-1,EventDateFrom)
)
```

Comment: You can accept this as your preferred answer by clicking the tick, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Example Working Query

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/118889/sql-return-rows-where-date-is-given-date-or-date-plus-dynamic-days

Query

```
SELECT Path
FROM #Events
WHERE EventDateFrom <= '2011/11/17 00:00:00'
AND DATEADD(day,NumberOfDays,EventDateFrom) >= '2011/11/17 00:00:00'
```